How to connect to SQL Server using workload identity in AKS using .NET framework?
When I am using work load identity to connect to SQL Server in AKS using .NET framework, I am getting this error

login failed for identity principal user

I excepted to be able to connect successfully using workload identity.
Thanks in advance.

Are you saying that you're running ASP.NET (for .NET Framework - not ASP.NET Core) in a Container and you're also running MSSQL Server in another Container? Or both in the same container?

Same container only

If your error message says "login failed for identity principal user," it indicates that the permissions you have in SQL Server for the identity principal are insufficient. The identity has to have sufficient permissions to the SQL server. Use workload identity to set up and connect your SQL Server in the AKS cluster. To do so, ensure you have a managed identity available.
az identity create --resource-group arkorg --name downtime-identity


Note down the client ID and resource ID of the above-managed identity and assign the Managed Identity to the AKS cluster.
az aks update --resource-group arkorg --name downtime --enable-managed-identity --assign-identity <resource-id-of-downtime-identity>


Create an Azure AD User in SQL Server
Grant Necessary Permissions to the Managed Identity
CREATE USER [<client-id-of-downtime-identity>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [<client-id-of-downtime-identity>];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [<client-id-of-downtime-identity>];

Update Your .NET Framework Application. Look at the Active Directory Managed Identity authentication section for better clarity.
Update your deployment YAML with the azure.workload.identity/client-id annotation
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sql-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sql-connection-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sql-connection-app
      annotations:
        azure.workload.identity/client-id: 03843c85-abcd-efg-hijk-51f37blmnop
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: sql-connection-app
        image: arkoacr.azurecr.io/sql-connection-app:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80



Reference:

Similar issue on Github
Connect to Azure SQL with Microsoft Entra authentication and SqlClient
Use Microsoft Entra Workload ID with Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)


your mixing both managed identity and work identity processes

This Command for az aks update --resource-group arkorg --name downtime --enable-managed-identity --assign-identity   only managed identity scenarios we mapping identity resource id.
